# json decode with jQuery using codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I need to know how can I append my array using jquery . following is my code

model in codeigniter

```
public function getranking(){

    $this->db->select('*')->from('tour_ranking');
    $this->db->join('teams','teams.team_id = tour_ranking.team_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();


}
```

this give output like

```
   [
{
"Rank_Id": "1",
"Tour_id": "1",
"Team_id": "1",
"match_palyed": "1",
"Points": "100",
"Rating": "1",
"match_loss": "0",
"match_win": "1",
"is_display": "1",
"team_id": "1",
"team_name": "pakistan",
"is_active": "0",
"short_name": "PK",
"image_ex": "Pk.png"
}
]
```

and jquery i am using is

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/main/ranking/',function(data){ count=0;
    $('#rank-table').append('<tr class="rankingTr"><td class="rankingTd" id="rank-teamName">'+data'team_name'+' </td><td class="rankingTd" id="rank-matchplayed">'+data.match_palyed+'</td><td class="rankingTd" id="rank-points">'+data.Points+'</td><td class="rankingTd" id="rank-rating">'+data.Rating+'</td></tr>')
 });
```

i can see result in my console hit but when i m appending this its giving me undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your output is array of objects, so you need to use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), as:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/main/ranking/',function(data){ 
    count=0;
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        //do your append here using val.points, val.short_name, etc
        console.log(val.short_name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving array instead of object. `[]`and`{}`is Array and Object respectively, make sure you don't mixed up with the two relationship of it.

You can fixed it by converting data from Array to Object.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/main/ranking/',function(data){ 
    data = data[0];  // just adding this line and you will get the object from first item in array.
    count=0;
    $('#rank-table').append('<tr class="rankingTr"><td class="rankingTd" id="rank-teamName">'+data'team_name'+' </td><td class="rankingTd" id="rank-matchplayed">'+data.match_palyed+'</td><td class="rankingTd" id="rank-points">'+data.Points+'</td><td class="rankingTd" id="rank-rating">'+data.Rating+'</td></tr>')
 });
```